# Web scraping: finding element after a DOM Tree change

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, web-crawler, dom-traversal

I am relatively new to web scraping/crawlers and was wondering about 2 issues in the event where a parsed DOM element is not found in the fetched webpage anymore:

1- Is there a clever way to detect if the page has changed? I have read that it's possible to store and compare hashes but I am not sure how effective it is.

2- In case a parsed element is not found in the fetched webpage anymore, if we assume that we know that the same DOM element still exists somewhere in the DOM Tree in a different location, is there a way to somehow traverse the DOM Tree efficiently without having to go over all of its nodes?

I am trying to find out how experienced developers deal with those two issues and would appreciate insights/hints/strategies on how to manage them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see this in your tag list so I thought I'd mention this before anything else: a tool called [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), designed specifically for web-scraping.

Web scraping is a messy process. Unless there's some long-standing regularity or direct relationship with the web site, you can't really rely on anything remaining static in the web page - certainly not when you scale to millions of web pages.

With that in mind:

1. There's no one-fit-all solution. Some ideas:

   - Use RSS, if available.
   - Split your scraping into crude categories where some categories have either implied or explicit timestamps (eg: news sites) you can use to trigger an update on your end.
   - You already mentioned this but hashing works quite well and is relatively cheap in terms of storage. Another idea here is to not hash the entire page but rather only dynamic or elements of interest.
   - Fetch HEAD, if available.
   - Download and store previous and current version of the files, then use a utility like diff.
   - Use a 3rd party service to detect a change and trigger a "refresh" on your end.

Obviously each of the above has its pros and cons in terms of processing, storage, and memory requirements.

2. As of version 4.x of BeautifulSoup you can use different HTML parsers, namely, [lxml](http://lxml.de/), which should allow you to use XPath. This will definitely be more efficient than traversing the entire tree manually in a loop.

Alternatively (and likely even more efficient) is using CSS selectors. The latter is more flexible because it doesn't depend on the content being in the same place; of course this assumes the content you're interested in retains the CSS attributes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer. I have a few follow up questions:1-what do you mean by Fetch HEAD? 2- I am actually using lxml but I am wondering how to parse the DOM tree efficiently with xPath in case i can't find the element anymore?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood it at first but I'm only using lxml.html to apply xpath.

Comment: I meant HTTP HEAD: you get an identical response to GET, but without the body. So, you can get the meta-information in the response headers without needing to worry about the rest of the page. This is useful because the headers include "Last-Modified" and "Content-Length", both of which you can use to decide if you want to refresh your copy.

Comment: With regards to #2: BS allows you to use CSS elements instead of XPath. This is only useful if the content of what you want is still available but perhaps was moved within the webpage but has the same CSS class as before (which is common). But, in terms of handling the error, I just wrap everything in try/except blocks and trigger a notification event to another part of my web scraping pipeline to let me know to either update the XPath or try a new one.

Comment: @Orochi1992 if the above helped, please consider marking it as the solution :)

Comment: Apologies, I was planning to select it as the answer by the end of next week. When it comes to error handling, do you update the xPath manually?

Comment: Cool, thanks! Ya, I manually update the xPath because either way I end up having to load the page to see why it broke. If you can get CSS selectors involved I find they tend to change less than the exact content location - they break less. Another idea is to split the page into element-level buckets, you can store those temporarily on error to quickly see if your content moved elsewhere without scouring pages.

Comment: sort of, now I know in which direction to search. I might ask something here later if it is alright.

Comment: Sure, hopefully I can help